# Kerning and page number problem after \foreignlanguage in xelatex

Tags: xetex, page-numbering, languages, polyglossia, kerning

While I use xelatex or lualatex, it seems that language rules remain in effect after the end of `\foreignlanguage{...}{...}` while `\begin{otherlanguage}{...}...\end{otherlanguage}` works as expected.

Am I misunderstood something or a bug was found ?

[image: pdfrendering]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{churchslavonic}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{churchslavonic}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\churchslavonicfont[Script=Cyrillic,Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase,HyphenChar=_]{FedorovskUnicode.otf}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{churchslavonic}{
  \cuKinovar{И҆}щи́те, и ѡбрѧ́щете
}

Acknowledgments

{\bf Acknowledgments}

\lipsum[1-17]

==========================

\begin{otherlanguage}{churchslavonic}

\cuKinovar{И҆}щи́те, и ѡбрѧ́щете

\end{otherlanguage}

Acknowledgments

{\bf Acknowledgments}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** As suggested by @ulrike-fischer, writing \bfseries instead of \bf solved the original kerning problem. Nevertheless, there is still a problem with \foreignlanguage, the page numbers use churchslavonic font style, but they should not.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: don't use \bf, the correct command is \bfseries.

Comment: you could try babel instead. Something like `\usepackage[russian.ancient,english]{babel}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}[Script=Cyrillic,Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase,HyphenChar=_]{FedorovskUnicode.otf}`

Comment: Yes, it works with babel. So the problem is somehow related to polyglossia I think.